# fs.rename ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, fs

I am getting in trouble then using fs.rename in node.js app. 
I already use the function below and it works as I would expect it to work.

```js
var fs =require("fs");
var path =require("path")
module.exports= function(oldPath, newPath){
    oldPath=path.join(__dirname, "..", "documents", "bka" , oldPath);
    newPath=path.join(__dirname, "..", "documents", "bka" , newPath);
    fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, (err)=>{if (err) console.log(err)});
}
```

Then I tried to use the function for another case.
oldPath exists. newPath doesn't exists. 
If I don't change newPath no error occurs. If I change it the error below occurs and I have no idea why:

```js
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ubuntu/workspace/documents/bka/7_Wall Street_1/9_Whg_Nr_22/7_bob' -> '/home/ubuntu/workspace/documents/bka/7_Wall Street_1/9_Whg_Nr_221/7_bob' at Error (native) errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'rename', path: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/documents/bka/7_Wall Street_1/9_Whg_Nr_22/7_bob', dest: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/documents/bka/7_Wall Street_1/9_Whg_Nr_221/7_bob' }
```

would be great if you could help me. I have seen some other people had similar problems in the past but I didn't find any answer that could make me understand the problem.

Thanks amit

Answer (score 4):

You're renaming the file `.../9_Whg_Nr_22/7_bob` to `.../9_Whg_Nr_221/7_bob`

This will only work if the directory `9_Whg_Nr_221` already exists, and my guess is that it doesn't, and `fs.rename` will *not* create that directory for you.

In these sorts of situations, where the target directory may not yet exist, you have to manually create the directory first, for instance using [`mkdirp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.

I kind of fixed it. The code is a mess now but it at least it does what it should.

```js
var path =require("path");
var mkdirp =require("mkdirp");
var shell = require("shelljs");
var Promise= require("bluebird");
module.exports= function(oldPath, newPath){
    oldPath=path.join(__dirname, "..", "documents", "bka" , oldPath);
    newPath=path.join(__dirname, "..", "documents", "bka" , newPath);
    var oldArr= oldPath.split("/");
    var newArr= newPath.split("/");     
    var np="";
    var op="";
      var createDir=(path)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            mkdirp(path, (err)=>{
                if (err) throw err
                resolve(path)
            });
        });
    }
    
    var copy =(from, to)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            shell.cp("-R",from+"/*", to);
            resolve();
        });
    }
    var rm= (path)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
             shell.rm("-R", path);
            resolve();
        });
    }
    
    var results=[]
    for( var i=0; i<oldArr.length; i++){
        op += oldArr[i]+"/";
        np += newArr[i]+"/";
        if(oldArr[i]!= newArr[i]){
            Promise.resolve()
            var result={}
            result.from=op;
            result.to=np;
            results.push(result);
        }
    }
    
    createDir(results[results.length-1].to)
        .then(()=>{ copy(results[results.length-1].from, results[results.length-1].to)
            .then(()=>{rm(results[0].from).then(()=>{
                results.pop();
            });
        });
    });
}
```